# Angle measurement shows only integer values, is it possible to increase the precision

Tags: interface, measurement

In Blender 2.92, the measure tool shows distances to the precision of 6 digits after the decimal point, but only integer angle values. [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/24108/91183) suggests that previous versions showed two digits after the decimal point.

The linked question has three answers:

- copy and paste that value, but I do not know how it is supposed to work;
- use N shortcut then "mesh display", but in my version nothing like that shows;
- use an extension;
- use a script.

Is there a simple way of increasing the precision to at least one digit after the decimal point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shipped add-on *MeasureIt Tools* allows you to set precision:

[image]

Comment: and gives you a nicer display